# How to recover from accidental deletion of the default feed

Tags: azure-artifacts

I have accidentally deleted (and then permanently deleted) the default feed which is created for a new organisation. I am now trying to create a new feed, which I realise will be project scoped, by going into the Artifacts section and clicking to add a new feed.

But, I can't get that far because as soon as I click on Artifacts, I get an error because of the deleted feed:

[image: Error Message]

I'd really welcome a pointer on how to recover from this.  Ideally, I'd like to recreate the original organization-scoped feed.

Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred when I deleted the default feed. The issue is reported in visualstudio.com developer community. Below is the solution provide in the community

> [Workaround]
> The problem extends to the whole organization, if you delete a feed permanently from one of the projects, you will not be able to see the feeds in any other projects within the organization.
> A quick workaround to fix the problem, go to User Settings > Preview Features > New Artifacts (Feeds) Experience turn it off
> View your feeds with the classic version, if they appear, then you can turn that feature on again.

[Click here for the solution link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Artifacts-failed-to-get-feed/10062928?space=21&q=Failed%20to%20get%20feed)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond Giltachy.  That solution has worked for me, so I am really grateful.  Thank you!!